# How to select password from dropdown and pass it as parameter to jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a problem. I use Jenkins to deploy application on machines. Depending on which machine i want to deploy new version I need to use different database passwords to run db migrations. I want to store credentials in Jenkins and for each deploy job select credentials set from dropdown which will be passed (just password ) to powershell script. I have Credentials Binding Plugin and Extended Choice Parameter Plugin. I thought it might help me with my problem, but I cannot find solution for this. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need only to do two things:

- add **Credential Parameter** in **This project is parameterized** section for possibility to select credentials set from dropdown.
- enable **Use secret text(s) or file(s)** option in **Build Environment** section. This will allow you to take credentials of various sorts and use them from shell build steps and the like. Each binding will define an environment variable.

If you have already created Jenkins credentials like these:
[image]
then you will be available to run your job using **Build with Parameters** button and select needed credentials:
[image]

So, after configuring, you don't need to dig in job configuration each time, all possible credentials will be automatically loaded, you need only select the needed one when run a job.

Comment: Ok. As I understood. I need to add binding for each password stored in credentials. Is it possible to select which password I want to use for each deploy job without digging in job configuration?

Comment: Updated answer. If I understand you correctly, you don't need to dig in job configuration. Just configure as I said and you will see.